# Streaming data into big query using Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-bigquery

Can anyone point me to any documentation on streaming data into big query using Dart/Flutter?

I'm pretty new to all this and cannot for the life of me find any Flutter specific documentation or precedence.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Dart/Flutter isn't one of the languages which has a directly maintained client library, but it looks like there's a discovery-based library.  The API method endpoint you need for streaming data is `bigquery.tabledata.insertAll`, which is surfaced in the dart library here it seems:

https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.bigquery.v2/TabledataResourceApi/insertAll.html

None of the docs in the BigQuery public documentation will contain Dart/Flutter code examples, but you can get more background on streaming data in  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

Answer (score 2):

Flutter --> Google Cloud Function --> BigQuery

Your best approach by far will be to use a Google Cloud Function to write to BigQuery. Architecturally, this is the right approach, though I could argue that putting a stream platform (like Google Pub/Sub) in the middle has some additional benefits. In your situation, however, I'd recommend going straight from Cloud Functions to BigQuery for simplicity since you're already going to have a learning curve and probably don't need the stream layer at this point.

There's good documentation for integrating Cloud Functions into Flutter, and it's quite intuitive to use.

Here are the official Flutter docs that talk about this integration path:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/overview/

Here's a good walkthrough on how to actually do it: https://rominirani.com/tutorial-flutter-app-powered-by-google-cloud-functions-3eab0df5f957

On the BigQuery side:
There's a very detailed walkthrough here on writing to BigQuery from Cloud Functions: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions
You can find more guides as well if you search Google.